# id parameter in R simmer package

Tags: r, simulation

There are several functions in the R simmer package that have the argument `id = 0`.   Usually the functions are associated with selecting a certain resource (e.g. `seize_selected`).  I haven't been able to find any documentation on what this parameter does other than `selection identifier for nested usage`.  Does anyone know what this means or have a use case for setting this to something other than its default value of 0?

I'm trying to see if it will help me select a coupled resource.  For example, if I select "Bar1" resource, then I have to select "Server1" as a related resource. The wording of the reference makes me think this might help, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what it is for. If you select a second resource, you lose your previous selection... unless you give it a different `id`. So, in your case:

```r
  ... %>%
  select("Bar1", id=0) %>%
  ...
  select("Server1", id=1) %>%
  ...
```

and then you can use those ids in other activities to refer to those selections.

Comment: Related question. Can I use the id parameter to refer to specific resource groups when selecting, seizing, and releasing? For example, I have a scenario where I want arrivals to seize a variable number of resources from three separate resource pools. Then the arrival will use (timeout) and release each pool in sequence. Problem is, I can't figure out how to release_selected such that it releases only from a specific pool.

Comment: You need to select all those resources in the first place with different IDs. Then you can release_selected them using the proper IDs in the order you need.